# How to make the filters work in this todo app created using react and redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Edit:

Changing the code as per Andrew's suggestion works.

I'm making a todo app using redux. I'm facing problem with filters ( show all todo, show active todo, show completed ).
The filters are returning new state. For instance, If I have 6 Todo tasks in my state and if 2 of them are completed. Now if I click on show completed filter it returns 2 tasks which is correct. But then if I click on show active or show all filter, it returns values from those 2 tasks and not from the earlier 6 tasks.

My app state is

```
state: {todo: []}
```

My Todo Item is

```
[
 {id: 1, text: 'Save Gotham!!', completed: false},
 {id: 2, text: 'Buy new jet', completed: true}
]
```

**Actions**

```
export function showAllTodo(state){
  // state will have id,text and completed flag, this is not same as app state
  return {
    type: SHOW_ALL_TODO,
    payload: state
  }
};

export function showCompletedTodo(state){
  let completedTodo = state.todo.filter( (item) => item.completed);
  return {
    type: SHOW_COMPLETED,
    payload: {todo: completedTodo}
  }
};


export function showActiveTodo(state){
  let activeTodo =  state.todo.filter( item => !item.completed)
  return {
    type: SHOW_ACTIVE,
    payload: {todo: activeTodo}
  }
};
```

**Reducer**

//Sample reducer

```
case SHOW_COMPLETED:
  return action.payload;
break;
```

Comment: Don't filter inside the action creators. Instead, put all the todos in state and the filter in state, and in your container filter accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will surely try this. But is it possible to do using above method ?

Comment: No because you'll be filtering todos and losing the original todos. You could include all the todos in the state and the current todos too though, along with the filter though I'd prefer the other way.

Comment: don't you also need a 'todos' piece of state?

Comment: @whs.bsmith  Todo is an array of object. I have updated the code.

Comment: how are you dispatching and where are you subscribing to these data?

Comment: @Envision.  That makes a lot more sense to store the individual todo items as an object, and then the list of them in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good practice to handle the filters in frontend itself. It can be done using a map/filter function. Example:

```
      let filteredState = { todo: [], visibilityFilter: ''};
      if(this.props.visibilityFilter == SHOW_ACTIVE){
        filteredState.todo = this.props.todo.filter( item => !item.completed )
      }
      if(this.props.visibilityFilter == SHOW_COMPLETED){
        filteredState.todo = this.props.todo.filter( item => item.completed )
      }
      if(this.props.visibilityFilter == SHOW_ALL_TODO){
        filteredState.todo = this.props.todo;
      }

      return (
        <ToDoItem todo={filteredState} />
      )
```

Comment: What if I have 10 todos: SHOW_ACTIVE will show 8 , SHOW_COMPLETED shows: 1 and SHOW_ALL_TODO shows 1 todos. But in backed there are are thousands of todos. How will I ask user to load more ? Load more or pagination only appears when the list on the screen is full, but the screen for SHOW_ALL_TODO and SHOW_COMPLETED is not full. Then ?